# string regex replace/prepend

Tags: javascript, regex, algolia

I need to transform a string from a user input into a search bar such that I prepend any word in the string with "contactTags:" that is NOT a special search character like (,),AND,OR,NOT such that the search input `(foo OR bar) AND baz NOT buz` becomes `(contactTags:foo OR contactTags:bar) AND contactTags:baz NOT contactTags:buz`

The end use case of this string will be to insert into the filters parameter of an algolia search. (But really this question is more about regular regex string replacement)

I can generate a regex pattern that gets me close, but I am having problems on the string replacement aspect:

```
const regex = /(?!OR|AND|NOT)\b[\w+]+\b/g;
let str = '(foo OR bar) AND baz NOT buz';


while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach(match => {
        str = str.replace(/(?!OR|AND|NOT)\b[\w+]+\b/,"contactTags:"+match)
    });
}

console.log(str)
```

which unfortunately yields me a trainwreck of: "(contactTags:foo:foo:foo:foo:foo:X10000 OR bar) AND baz NOT buz"

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get the idea it will have a zero-width match? Specifically, your regex consumes `[\w+]+`. Also, `[\w+]+` is redundant and possibly harmful. Use `\w+` instead.

Comment: `str.replace(/\b(?!(OR|AND|NOT)\b)\w+/g, 'contactTags:$&')` filters words according to the regex definition of a word - but yours might differ. Can you add more details regarding possible matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `exec` for replacement. Just call `.replace` like this:

```js
const regex = /\b(?!(?:OR|AND|NOT)\b)\w+\b/ig;
let str = '(foo OR bar) AND baz NOT buz';

str = str.replace(regex, 'contactTags:$&');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: +1 Whoa, I did not know you could do that dollar sign, ampersand thing, super cool! I would have just used a function, but this is so much cooler!

Comment: @joetom - the `$&` is a match variable representing group 0, i.e. the whole match. It's not really a good idea to use it though as it adds a multiple X overhead to the replacement. If it's a 1-off thing, it's ok, otherwise specify a capture group within the regex `/(?!OR|AND|NOT)\b(\w+)\b/` and reference it with a `$1` in the replacement.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
const regex = /(?!OR|AND|NOT)\b([\w]+)\b/g;
let str = '(foo OR bar) AND baz NOT buz';

console.log(str.replace(regex, 'contactTags:$1'))
```

Comment: I had marked @anubhava's answer as accepted answer but moved it to @JamPow's only because it was first and because @sln 's comment above seems to indicate that `$1` is better than `$&`.   But thank you to you both! It seems to work just fine!

Comment: @JakeLowen `$1` is worse than `$&`. It is additional overhead for the regex engine. This answer is worse than anubhava's because the lookahead is not anchored after a word boundary. `/(?!OR|AND|NOT)\b([\w]+)\b/g` will run `(?!OR|AND|NOT)` at *every* position inside a word. When placed after `\b`, it is only executed after a word boundary. And it is easier to check for a word boundary first than for a group with several alternations. Moreover, `[\w]` is equal to `\w` - why use a single atom in a separate character class?

Comment: I totally agree with @WiktorStribiżew , `$1` is definitely worse than `$&` in terms of memory usage. It also shortens your regex by avoiding an unnecessary captured group.

Comment: @JakeLowen: In Perl versions prior to 5.20, `$&` usage caused serious slowdowns of Perl program execution. Perhaps, sln meant that sort of "problem". However, you are not using Perl, and `$&` is OK to use *everywhere* where it is supported. In Perl v.5.20+, too.